# Adding one hour to string date

Tags: excel

I have a schedule which appears in cells as (string date) 7/31/2012 11:09:00 PM and I want to place corresponding in two separate cells showing date and time with one hour time difference which might set the date off into the next day. How do I add one hour as well?

Answer (score 1):

If your string date is in A1, in B2 you can do `=Hour(a1)+1` which should return 12 (or 00 if you use 24 hr).  Same with date, just to `=day(a1)+1`

Comment: DAY(A1)+1 will simply give a number, e.g. today is 29th April so DAY(A1)+1 will just give 30, same with HOUR - see my answer to get a date and time

Comment: Just curuious - why use mod() and int() for the date and time? Couldn't you just make a cell like `=hour(a1)+1&" and the date is "&date(a1)+1`?  I figured OP could use the day() and hour() and work in as needed.

Comment: MOD and INT should give the required results, e.g. for the example given you'd get 12:09 AM and 8/1/2012. HOUR function won't give you minutes and date needs arguments for year, month and day

Answer (score 1):

Try like this for date

`=INT(A1+"1:00")`

and for time

`=MOD(A1+"1:00",1)`

format result cells in required date or time format

These work even when the added hour takes you in to a new day